# Check if an entry is already in a livedata list wihout looping through the list

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build an app to help me track some of the tasks we have to do in the game.

I have a Firebase Firestore database that store all the tasks and I download at the application launch the data and add only the one I don't have.
Here is my entry model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry_table")
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid: Long?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "target") val target: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "position") val position: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "starred") val starred: Boolean = false

) {
    constructor(): this(null, "", "", 0, 0, starred = false)
}
```

Since I download the document from the firestore database I cannot set an ID before inserting the entries in my SQLite database. 
This means that I cannot use the "contains" method on my livedata list (since the entries I recieve has a "null" id and the one from the database has an id). I need to loop though all the data, here is the code:

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun insertEntry(entry: Entry) {
    for (doc in entriesList.value!!){
        if (doc.description == entry.description && doc.title == entry.title) {
            Log.d("MAIN_AC", "Entry already saved $entry")
            return
        }
    }
    entryDAO.insertEntry(entry)
}
```

My code works but I am not satisfied with it, is there a better way to make this happen? I was hoping that the contains method could ignore some arguments (in my case the autogenerated ID)

Comment: Have you considered downloading into a temp table and using `INSERT FROM SELECT`?

Comment: Also consider maintaining a timestamp (both sides) so that you only request tasks that are likely to be new/changed since your last download. Just a quick glance at your code raises some perf questions.

Comment: @AndreArtus thanks for the comment, I wanted to try the technology to be sure that I will be able to do what I want. I have to add a lot of information, I did not think of a timestamp however and this will be a great addition :)

Comment: You see in my example that I add a list of items, not individual items, right? If you search "sqlite batch insert" you will see pages indicating that single inserts (if you have a list to insert) is bad for performance. Looping like you do for every insert is also bad for perf. It may work fine for small sample data, then bog down in production. My test data always has at least one very large/complex set.

Comment: You are probably using `constructor(): this(null, "", "", 0, 0, starred = false)` to get around some issues with loading the entity from your remote source.This is setting yourself up for future problems. Split the local and remote model. You can bind them with an interface if you must. Don' t use parameter-less/default constructors for entities, it's a headache waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can go about, assuming you are using Room, it is to annotate your insert function (in the relevant DAO) with `OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE`.

e.g.

```
@Dao
interface EntryDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(list: List<Entry>)
    // or (if you want the inserted IDs)    
    // fun insert(list: List<Entry>) : LongArray
}
```

Be sure to also annotate your entity with the relevant unique index.

e.g.

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry_table",
    indices = [Index(value = ["title", "description"], unique = true)]
       )
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String
    //...
                )
```

Primary keys should not be null-able, you can `.map` to `Entry` wit `uid` = 0. If you are using the same entity model both locally and remotely that is probably not the best idea.